# Send an email with contact form data to myself with Meteor/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, meteor, contact-form

I am trying to figure out how to send an email to myself using data collected from a contact form. I am building an app using Meteor and Bootstrap. I am open to writing the data into a Google Spreadsheet if that's a lot easier, but would prefer to send an email. Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return check_contact();">
                <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center">
                  <img style="max-width:140px;" src="LagoonLogoContact.png">
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"><i class="fa fa-user" id="contact-name-icon"></i></label>

                    <div class="col-lg-11">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="name">
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-1 control-label"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" id="contact-email-icon"></i></label>

                    <div class="col-lg-11">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="email">
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-msg" class="col-lg-1 control-label"><i class="fa fa-pencil" id="contact-message-icon"></i></label>

                    <div class="col-lg-11">
                      <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="message" id="contact-message"></textarea>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Close</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT (Below HTML on same page):

```
 <script>

    function check_contact() {

      var name = document.getElementById('contact-name').value;
      var email = document.getElementById('contact-email').value;
      var message = document.getElementById('contact-message').value;
      var reg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;

      if(name == "" || email == "" || message == ""){

        document.getElementById('contact-name').style.border = "1px solid black";
        document.getElementById('contact-name-icon').style.color = "black";

        document.getElementById('contact-email').style.border = "1px solid black";
        document.getElementById('contact-email-icon').style.color = "black";

        document.getElementById('contact-message').style.border = "1px solid black";
        document.getElementById('contact-message-icon').style.color = "black";

        if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById('contact-name').style.border = "1px solid #ff6464";
        document.getElementById('contact-name-icon').style.color = "#ff6464";
        }

        if(email == "" || !reg.test(email)){
        document.getElementById('contact-email').style.border = "1px solid #ff6464";
        document.getElementById('contact-email-icon').style.color = "#ff6464";
        }

        if(message == ""){
        document.getElementById('contact-message').style.border = "1px solid #ff6464";
        document.getElementById('contact-message-icon').style.color = "#ff6464";
        }

        return false;

      }
      else{
        if(reg.test(email)){

          console.log("working here");

          var nameSend = $('#contact-name').val();
          var emailSend = $('#contact-email').val();
          var messageSend = $('#contact-message').val();

          var dataSend = 'nameSend=' + name + '&emailSend=' + email + '&messageSend=' + message;
          console.log(dataSend);


          return true;
          }

        else {
          return false;
        }
      }

    }

  </script>
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The [email](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email) package allows you to send emails very easily. Note that `email.send()` only works on the server so you'll need to define a server method and call it from the client.

You also need to be careful not to create a spam vector: if the client can call this function with all parameters then anyone can easily script it to send out a bazillion emails. Usually you don't want both the recipient and the body field to come from the client.